# addAttributeToSelect not working with core/resource_iterator?

Tags: collection

```
public function run()
{
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')

    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')
            ->walk($products->getSelect()->limit(10), array(array($this, 'getLine')));

}

public function getLine($args)
{
    var_dump($args['row']);
}
```

In my `getLine()` method I get no `name` but `addFinalPrice()` works:

```
array(16) {
  ["entity_id"]=>
  string(2) "61"
  ["entity_type_id"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["attribute_set_id"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["type_id"]=>
  string(6) "simple"
  ["sku"]=>
  string(15) "50-F01010001-03"
  ["has_options"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["required_options"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["created_at"]=>
  string(19) "2011-07-05 18:30:48"
  ["updated_at"]=>
  string(19) "2014-09-04 07:34:21"
  ["indexed_price"]=>
  string(7) "14.5000"
  ["price"]=>
  string(7) "14.5000"
  ["final_price"]=>
  string(7) "14.5000"
  ["minimal_price"]=>
  string(7) "14.5000"
  ["min_price"]=>
  string(7) "14.5000"
  ["max_price"]=>
  string(7) "14.5000"
  ["tier_price"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Same problem with `image`, `price` and every other attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the `core/iterator` resource model does not work well with EAV models, because it directly works with the query and does not use any of the collection specific features.

This is what usually happens when loading an EAV collection (I'll simplify a bit):

- select basic data from the entity table (this is what `$collection->getSelect()` does
- load the attributes from the value tables with an **additional query** and add this data to each loaded model

This all happens in the `load()` method (see `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract::_loadAttributes()` if you want to see the implementation details)

**Since the reason for using the resource iterator is usually that you don't want to load all data at once, you cannot use this feature in a reasonable way.**

I tried to build a single query with joins instead, but soon ran into the problem that MySQL "only" allows 63 joins at a time. If you only need a few attributes, it might work for you, though.

Otherwise your best bet is to load and process the collection in chunks like this:

```
$ids = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->getAllIds();

$page = 1;
do {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addIdFilter($ids)
        ->setPageSize(100)
        ->setPage($page);
    $results = $collection->load();
    // do stuff ...
    $page++;
} while ($results->count());
```

Comment: I used the iterator because of a memory limit problem but it turned out using the iterator here use even more memory. I fixed it be reverting to normal collection and `ini_set('memory_limit','512M');`.

Answer (score 7):

You got to use the second parameter `'inner'` like this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
     ->getCollection()
     ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'image'), 'inner');
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614533/magento-collection-iterator-cannot-get-additional-attribute

Comment: This is the JOIN solution that I was refering to. Good if you only need a few attributes, but don't try it with `addAttributeToSelect('*')`

Comment: Use 'left' if you want to include entities where the eav attribute is not set at all.