# Get All Orders from Database

Tags: orders, collection, magento-1, sales-order

I am following [this](http://www.justwebdevelopment.com/blog/magento-get-items-in-order/) article. I would like to retrieve all Orders from Database. Can anyone say how can I do that??

Answer (score 1):

Using collection you can do it easily with one single line:

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection');
```

Then depending on what you want to do you can loop through them:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    // Do something
}
```

NB: using `foreach` may be resource and time consuming, I suggest you think about using the walk iterator by reading this link: [Is it possible to iterate over Magento collections with pagination natively?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/is-it-possible-to-iterate-over-magento-collections-with-pagination-natively)

Answer (score 1):

Been answered the Magento Way. If you want to just excess them in the database themselves than let me know as it's a combination of several areas.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9741114/how-to-get-all-orders-and-all-invoices-from-php-in-magento

Answer (score 0):

If some one needs to read huge amount of data using command object, without having memory problems, you can use magento walk iterator.

example code on
http://www.rosenborgsolutions.com/collection-walk-iterator.php